# Also, the building will remain closed to all staff unless otherwise notified by your supervisor

Tags: commas

Do I need another comma between staff and otherwise?

Comment: When in doubt, leave it out!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: You don't *need* the comma, no. Just like you don't *need* an em dash. But you *can* put an em dash there. Just like you *can* a comma.

Comment: The problem I have with that sentence is "**your** supervisor" - it sounds odd to suddenly be talking directly to the individual. I would say "...all staff except those notified by their supervisor".